# CSS 3 - left border all except first div

Tags: css

I want to give all my .uk-width-medium-1-3 a left border except the first one of each line. 
Please check [my site](http://auto-troesch.mediafish.es/)

Right now I have a border on all boxes but always only want to have one on the second and third of each line.

Thanks for some help

I added to the CSS:

```
:not(:first-child)
```

but that does not help...

Answer (score 5):

It isn't the first child, the heading `.uk-panel-title` is. Use first of type instead. Like so:

```
.tm-bottom-b .uk-width-medium-1-3:not(:first-of-type) {
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
}
```

You always have to be careful with `first-child`. It selects the first child, no matter what type or HTML it is (excepting `:before` and `:after` elements because they are not really physically present HTML structural elements). The [:first-of-type](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#first-of-type-pseudo) pseudo class, however, selects the element in a set of children that is the first of its kind among those children, e.g. first `p` element, first `div` element and so on.

Comment: sorry that only removes the first border of the first three but not of the first one on the bottom - additionally it moves all boxes on the bottom to the right and I have an empty box on the left... it somehow does not float left anymore...

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want no border for every first `div.uk-width-medium-1-3`, to achieve that using css you have to group your div by **3's** and apply a border to all, then add a second rule that will remove all first div's left border.

an example would be

```
div.uk-panel div.uk-width-medium-1-3:nth-child(1){
    border-left:none;
}
```

or

```
div.uk-panel div.uk-width-medium-1-3:not(:first-child){
    border-left:none;
}
```

Comment: ...yes I want to achieve that always the first of the line has no border left. But it is a module that pulls all the information from the DB and I am not really sure how to group always 3 divs in one div as the layout of the module is only one div... don't know if you understand what I mean...